# What is the distance correlation for Anscombe’s quartet?

Tags: correlation, dataset, distance-covariance

Is the newer descriptive statistic ([distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation)) able to resolve these troubling four datasets ([Anscombe’s quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet))?

Comment: An interesting question. But may I suggest you first to [compute](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/183930/3277) it for Anscombe’s quartet datasets? Having the coefficient values before your eyes you might answer your own Q, or might generate specific issues to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the distance correlation values are different, respectively:

1. 0.8239139
2. 0.8688329
3. 0.9064762
4. 0.8067981

[Code](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=Ew6x4REo&version=30)

[image]