# Methods For Measuring Non-Linear Correlation?

Tags: correlation

I have been learning about standard methods in Statistics such as the [Pearson's Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient), [Spearman's Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) and [Kendall's Tau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient).

My understanding of this so far is that:

- Pearson Correlation Coefficient measures the linear correlation between two sets of data
- Spearman's Correlation measures the "monocity" between two sets of data (e.g. do they both increase and decrease at the same time?)
- Kendall's Tau measures the ordinal association between two sets of data - supposedly Kendall's Tau is similar to the Spearman Correlation, but Kendall's Tau has a more logical confidence intervals.

I had the following question - **can any of these methods be used for measuring a specific form of "Non Linear Correlation" between two sets of data?**

For example - suppose I want to see how strongly two sets of data are correlated relative to a "second order curve" :

[image]

Is there something that could measure the "curved correlation"?

The two ideas I came up with:

- Try to use some data transformations (e.g. Log) to transform one of the variables into a more linear pattern that will make it suitable for one of the above measures
- Fit a polynomial regression model (of order 2) to this data and measure the MSE

But I am not sure if either of these approaches are suitable.

Comment: Interesting question. Some of the trouble of defining a curved correlation will be deciding on what kind of curvature you want to measure. After all, a logarithm-type of graph has different curvature than a quadratic. Further, determining the sign will be challenging, since many curves (such as quadratics) allow for increasing and decreasing sections. I’ve wondered if the concavity of a parabola (up-opening vs down-opening) could be used for this, but parabolas are just one type of curve. (Maybe you can do this if you restrict to convex or concave functions.)

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "measuring"? If you want a measure of the "strength" of such a correlation, then you could indeed run a polynomial regression and report the MSE. Possibly cross-validated, otherwise if you re-ran this for higher order polynomials, you would "find" that the "second-order correlation" is smaller than the "third-order correlation" and so on. Conversely, if you want to do statistical inference, the null and alternative hypotheses will need some thinking about - are $x$ and $x^3$ for $-1<x<1$ "significantly second order correlated"? ...

Comment: ... (2) Especially for inference, the question comes up whether you want to test a *specific* polynomial correlation, or a *general* second-order polynomial, or a general polynomial of *up to* second order. Perhaps you could explain what you want to do with such a nonlinear correlation?

Comment: Another way to consider Stephan's comments is that *every* regression you could estimate for the two variables in your plot is, in a sense, a correlation measurement. Testing and comparing arbitrarily many regressions has problems with false discovery and statistical validity, so "just try stuff" isn't a great way to go about it: you need to be specific about what questions you want to ask your data & how you want to ask it. The plot you show is roughly monotonic & Spearman's correlation would characterize the extent. Lots of nonlinear functions are monotonic, so Spearman's is **an** answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in **distance correlation**.

**distance correlation** measures both linear and nonlinear association between two random variables or random vectors. This is in contrast to Pearson's correlation, which can only detect a linear association between two random variables.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation

Comment: [For more about distance correlation, click here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183572/understanding-distance-correlation-computations)